# AngularJS вопрос по расположению логики

Tags: angularjs, frontend

AngularJS для меня новый, поэтому при изучении у меня возник вопрос по расположению логики в контроллере. Является ли хорошей практикой писать логику такого рода(см.код ниже) в контроллере? Прочитал статьи по данной теме но так и "ненашупал" для себя ту самую грань - где можно, а где ненужно. Может кто-то поделится линком на священное писание по структурированию приложения с пояснениями?

```
 app.factory('Epg', ['TvServerService', 'NgTimeManager', function(TvServerService, NgTimeManager){

function findClosestTelecast(a, g) {
  return a.reduce(function (p, c) {
    return Math.abs(c - g) < Math.abs(p - g) ? c : p;
  });
}

return {
    epgTelecast: 
    function (channelInfo){

        if (channelInfo !== 0) {
            var arr = channelInfo,
                temp = [],
                result = 0,
                closest = 0,
                perviousTelecast = "",
                nextTelecast = "",
                time = NgTimeManager.getTime() / 1000,
                length = arr.length;

            for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++){
                temp.push(arr[i].time_start);
            }

            closest = findClosestTelecast(temp, time);

            for ( var j = 0; j < length; j++){
                if (arr[j].time_start === closest) {
                    result = arr[j];
                    perviousTelecast = arr[j - 1];
                    nextTelecast = arr[j + 1];
                    break;
                }
            }
           return [result.text, perviousTelecast.text, nextTelecast.text];

        } else {
            return "Нет данных";
        }

    }
}}]);
```

Этот код ищет какая телепередача должна идти в данный момент исходя из текущего времени и возвращает массив строк с текущей, прошлой и следующей передачей.

Answer (score 0):

Самый практичный гайд по angular 1, имхо:

[https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide/blob/master/README-ru-ru.md#Контроллеры](https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide/blob/master/README-ru-ru.md#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B)

в частности по вашему вопросу:

- Держите контроллеры настолько маленькими на сколько это возможно.
- Не помещайте бизнес-логику в контроллеры. Вынесите её в сервис.

Использование бизнес-логики или хранение состояния приложения в контроллерах не рекомендуется по следующим причинам:

- Контроллеры инициализируются для каждого view и уничтожаются с ним же
- Контроллеры нельзя переиспользовать - они завязаны на view
- Контроллеры не могут быть использованы при внедрении зависимости (dependency injection)